# How do I get a number preference in a fennec addon's options box

Tags: firefox-addon, fennec

In fennec, the options box is handled differently. I want to know how to get a number preference in the options box

Answer (score 0):

Have you read http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2009/09/fennec-handling-add-on-options/ or https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Extensions/Options?

For integer settings you need to do what's suggested there, then use `<setting type="integer"`.

Comment: Thanks for that. None of those pages said anything about an 'integer' setting type

Comment: Yeah, I went hunting the source for this: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mobile-browser/source/chrome/content/bindings/setting.xml